# Add button to Word ribbon for Citrix

Tags: ms-word, ribbon, citrix

If users are launching word through Citrix and no matter the changes you make, word will always look the same as it did once you restart the sessions, is is possible to configure word to keep -say a macro and a ribbon button that triggers that macro instead of defaulting to its original layout?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following to save/restore the Word settings from the local profile:

http://www.peppercrew.nl/index.php/2011/08/unable-to-use-the-office-2010-ribbon-toolbar-for-excel-and-word-with-roaming-profiles-on-terminal-server-windows-2003/